# Combine 3 sheets into one with importrange

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

Goal: Merge 2 sheets into the main sheet all in one sheet via importrange
Problem: All the columns are in different orders

[image]

I would like to importrange the 2 sheets in [client master sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Er_6mSY5TFJ5sb_DDRc6QY3aIzqen_QfVYg3FvBFZ3I/edit#gid=0) into the [main sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SjREILtAX6fnUvYbq2kgR-VmHuw-QfQEslBSKCIOWs8/edit#gid=0) in one table. Is that possible while the columns are not in the same orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Er_6mSY5TFJ5sb_DDRc6QY3aIzqen_QfVYg3FvBFZ3I", "Sheet 2!A2:E"),
 "select Col2,Col3,Col1,Col5,Col4 where Col1 is not null", 0);
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Er_6mSY5TFJ5sb_DDRc6QY3aIzqen_QfVYg3FvBFZ3I", "Sheet 3!A2:E"),
 "select Col2,Col4,Col1,Col3,Col5 where Col1 is not null", 0)}
```

[image: 0]